# How to merge one WordPress site with another?

Tags: wordpress

I need to merge my one WordPress website with another, now I am doing like this. I have downloaded everything from number one WordPress site's uploads directory and uploaded it into my targeted WordPress install uploads directory. Exported Posts from number one WordPress and imported it into the targeted Wordpress site.

Now the problem is all posts images loading from the old domain, how can I fix this?? am I doing the wrong way? do I need to do anything when importing so all old domina replace with the current domain?

Comment: That's not going to work, although you could conceivably make corrections at some point if you really had to. Maybe you can be more more clear about what you mean by "merge" the two sites. It could be that an export/import routine or set of functions would be adequate to your real objectivs.

Comment: Have you tried using the built-in import/export tools to add your posts from one page to another? After that, you can still have a look at fixing URLs and whatnot, but the importer should do an okayish job already.

Comment: @ CK MacLeod I have 2 websites, I want to migrate all of my contents from site A to site B.

Comment: @flomei I am using export / import but my issue is in every post I can see old domain for images.

Comment: In that case one of the many "search and replace" plugins for the database might help you to change the old URLs to the new one. You should give it a try.